# crash on "UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath"

Tags: ios, crash, uicollectionviewcell, prepareforreuse

I have a UICollectionView, while the cell is reused, then crashed.
Below is the stack while crash.

0
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_msgSend + 32

1
UIKitCore
-[UIView(Animation) _removeAllAnimations:] + 100

2
UIKitCore
-[UIView(Animation) _removeAllAnimations:] + 244

3
UIKitCore
-[UIView(Animation) _removeAllAnimations:] + 244

4
UIKitCore
-[UIView(Animation) _removeAllAnimations:] + 244

5
UIKitCore
-[UIView(Animation) _removeAllAnimations:] + 244

6
UIKitCore
-[UIView(Animation) _removeAllAnimations:] + 244

7
UIKitCore
-[UIView(Animation) _removeAllAnimations:] + 244

8
UIKitCore
-[UICollectionViewCell prepareForReuse] + 228

9
UIKitCore
-[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 400

10
UIKitCore
-[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 104

11
myapp
-[myCollectionView collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]

Can you help me? I'm really not understand why crash in here.

Comment: Post the stack trace from Stack trace pane in Xcode . This may be related to mistake in the reuse identifier name . Have you registered the cell?

Comment: I'm sure the cell identifier had registed.

Answer (score 0):

Check you cell identifier. Make sure it is need to set as same with set in the storyboard.

Follow below screenshots.
[image]
[image]